# Can we have custom field in subresource url in eve

Tags: mongodb, flask, eve

I am using eve 0.7.2 and flask 0.12 and mongodb. I am trying to build sub resource.

```
user/<regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}"):user_id>/abc
```

The above url is my subresource. Instead of using mongo object id in place **user_id** whether I can use some other like **place** which is in my document.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I trying to create sub resource. In which i need some custom field instead of ObjectId like `user/<placename>/aaa` instead of `user/<objectid>/aaa`